# Froala Wysiwyg - adding custom and toolbar buttons in a custom dropdown

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, froala

I'm trying to create a `more` custom dropdown for adding all the toolbar buttons under it when toolbarXS is activated (all the missing icons in the XS should be under the `more` dropdown.
unfortunately the docs aren't that clear and outputting only text options which does nothing besides showing.

i was wondering if anybody could help in how to do it.

i.e

```
// define annotation button for imagePopup
$.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('annotationIcon', { NAME: 'pencil'}); // the icon
$.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('annotation', { // the button 
  title: 'Annotation',
  icon: 'annotationIcon',
  undo: true, // Save the button action into undo stack.
  focus: true, // Focus inside the editor before the callback.
  showOnMobile: true, // Show the button on mobile or not.
  refreshAfterCallback: true, // Refresh the buttons state after the callback.
  // Called when the button is hit.
  callback: function () {
    annotateImage(this);
  }
})

// Define `more` dropdown button.
$.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('moreDropdown', {
  title: 'More',
  icon: 'More',
  undo: true,
  focus: true,
  type: 'dropdown',
  options: {
    "annotation": 'annotation'
  },
});
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
the only way i could figure out now is to use

```
html: function() {
  return 'HTML_CODE'
}
```

and just write all the ul by myself which is disgusting and doesn't seem like the proper way of doing it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with froala guys! 
[Custom popup](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/custom/popup/)
is a solution for implementing a popup with toolbar buttons as a dropdown.

Thanks